# what is the version relationship about postgresql-devel and postgresql

Tags: centos, postgresql

Are the postgresql-devel version have a relationship with postgresql? is it have a version matrix? if I installed postgresql 13, how to install the postgresql 13 mapped postgresql-devel version in the centos? I read the official document and did not found any relationship. I have installed postgresql 13 in the centos:

```
postgresql13-libs-13.3-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
postgresql13-13.3-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
postgresql13-server-13.3-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
```

but when I using this command to install postgresql-devel:

```
dnf install postgresql-devel
```

shows package conflicts:

```
 file /usr/lib64/libpq.so.5 from install of postgresql-libs-9.2.24-7.el7_9.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libpq5-14.0-42PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
```

version `9.2.24-7.el7_9` mapped to postgresql 9? how to install the postgresql 13 mapped postgresql-devel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `postgresql-devel` contains the headers, tools and documentation for creating programs that interface with PostgreSQL database with its own native API (instead of some standard interface API like ODBC or JDBC).

The corresponding development package for `postgresql13-13.3-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm` is `postgresql13-devel-13.3-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm`. It also has the RPM `provides` attribute indicating that it's a valid substitute for `postgresql-devel`:

```
# rpm -q --provides -p postgresql13-devel-13.3-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm 
warning: postgresql13-devel-13.3-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 442df0f8: NOKEY
postgresql13-devel-13.3-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
postgresql-devel >= 13.3-1PGDG.rhel7
postgresql13-devel = 13.3-1PGDG.rhel7
postgresql13-devel(x86-64) = 13.3-1PGDG.rhel7
```

So, once you install `postgresql13-devel`, any other package depending on `postgresql-devel` should consider the dependency satisfied, unless that package specifically requires a `postgresql-devel` version being something less than `13.3-1PGDG.rhel7`.

Answer (score 0):

using this command to install the postgresql-devel:

```
dnf install postgresql13-devel
```